Which UART can I use to send character to Raspberry Pi during boot process?
I am using Raspberry Pi 3 model B and Raspberry Pi 4 model B. I connect 3 pins: GND, GPIO14 (UART_TX) and GPIO15 (UART_RX) with my PC and use Minicom to display the boot message. However, I can not use my PC host to send character to Pi during the boot process of Pi (to go into shell if pressing on F1). Can anyone tell me Which UART can I use to send character from my PC host to Raspberry Pi?
My goal is to use Raspberry Pi without connecting Raspberry Pi with keyboard through USB port.

Why would you want "to send character to Pi during the boot process of Pi"? What do you hope to achieve.

I want to go to UEFI Shell without using USB keyboard
